# Sending corrupted csv line over the socket in Python 3

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, struct

I build a sensor unit where data are gathered at one Raspberry Pi and send to another's over the network. 
My first Pi creates a line with multiple readings from different sensors. It supposed to create a server and send it to clients. The client Pis needs to receive the sentence, do further processing or visualisation.

To test my solutions I want to read data from a txt file, which was build in an experiment. The problem is that sometimes data are corrupted, has different format depending on sensor and rows can be different for different set-ups.

I have build a function which suppose to change the input line to bytes. (I tried different methods but only this clunky function is the closest to any results). But it does not convert over the network

```
import struct

message = ['First sensor', 'second data', 'third',1, '19.04.2016', 0.1]

def packerForNet(message): 
    pattern = ''
    newMessage = []
    for cell in message:
        if isinstance( cell, int ):
            pattern += ('I')
            newMessage.append(cell)
        elif isinstance( cell, float ):
            pattern += ('d')
            newMessage.append(cell)
        elif isinstance(cell, str):
            pattern += (str(len(cell)))
            pattern += ('s')
            newMessage.append(cell.encode('UTF-8'))
        else:
            cell = str(cell)
            pattern += (len(cell))
            pattern += ('s')
            newMessage.append(cell.encode('UTF-8'))            
    return (newMessage, pattern)

newMessage, pattern = packerForNet(message)
patternStruct = struct.Struct(pattern)
packedM = patternStruct.pack(*newMessage)
```

The output from the function does not unpack correctly:

```
packedM = b'First sensorsecond datathird\x01\x00\x00\x0019.04.2016\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xb9?'
56
    print('unpacked = %s' % patternStruct.unpack(packedM))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

In addition I need to know the `pattern` to unpack it on the client side so in general it doesn't have sense.

In final version the server needs to work in the way that after client connects it will send to the client line from the sensors every millisecond. Sensors parsing is implemented in C and at the moment it creates a txt file for off-line processing. I can't change the way the sensor's line are made.

I don't know how to pack the list of different types and constantly send such lists to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does unpack correctly. The problem is not with the unpacking, but with the print.

Try:

```
unpackedM = patternStruct.unpack(packedM)
print(unpackedM)
```

unpackedM is a tuple of multiple values. The formatting of the string with the tuple failed.

EDIT:
To convert entire objects you can use python [msgpack](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python). That is what we use in communication python to python and php to python.

Comment: Do you know any other way to pack data like this, not knowing what would be in the line?At the moment client side need to know the pattern before unpacking so it needs to be send before the data. It is completely inefficient.

Comment: We use [msgpack](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python) to communicate python to python and also php to python. You can serialize an entire object with it. JSON would be another possibility.

Comment: can you please add a word about msgpack to the official answer? Then I can accept it as solution. (I tested the package it works great)